# Populating List with binary search

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search

I have List filled with file names. I need to populate anther List with search results. This search result must be done by binary search, with next specification: keyword may match file name or it's Substring(0, key.Length).
e.g. keyword = "car"
search results = "car.gif", "carffur.pdf" etc. but not "mobilecar.jar"

my binary search:

```
    class Search
{
    private const int KEY_NOT_FOUND = -1;

    public static int BinarySearch<T>(List<T> A, T key, IComparer<T> comparer, int imin, int imax)
    {
        // test if array is empty
        if (imax < imin)
            // set is empty, so return value showing not found
            return KEY_NOT_FOUND;
        else
        {
            // calculate midpoint to cut set in half
            int imid = imin + ((imax - imin) / 2);
            int compareResult = comparer.Compare(A[imid], key);
            // three-way comparison
            if (compareResult > 0)
                // key is in lower subset
                return BinarySearch<T>(A, key, comparer,imin, imid - 1);
            else if (compareResult < 0)
                // key is in upper subset
                return BinarySearch<T>(A, key, comparer, imid + 1, imax);
            else
                // key has been found
                return imid;
        }
    }
}
```

my comparer class:

```
    class SubStringComparison : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x.Length > y.Length && x.Substring(0, y.Length).Equals(y))
            return 0;

        return String.Compare(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
private void backgroundWorkerSearch_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchForFiles();
    }

    private void SearchForFiles()
    {
        List<string> files = listBoxFiles.Items.OfType<string>().ToList();
        searchResults = new List<string>();
        listBoxFiles.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    int index = Search.BinarySearch<string>(files, textBoxFileToSearch.Text, new SubStringComparison(), 0, files.Count - 1);
                    if (index == -1)
                        break;
                    else
                        searchResults.Add(files[index]);
                }
            }));
    }
```

Comment: Please show effort and explanation what "search result must be done by binary search". Normally this is done by `fileNames.OrderBy(....)` but your requirement is very unclear.

Comment: I shouldn't use any built in .net method. I must write it myself.
The problem is that when I use myself written binary search it returns me one result every time, but I need it to return another results too.

Comment: What are you looking on SO - permission to do that? Please make it clear what your problem  is with "write it myself" so help can be provided.

Comment: A list of your homework problems is not a *question*. If you're having difficulty with homework that's fine: show your work so far and ask a *clear, specific question* about it. No one here is going to do your work for you.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov here I wrote code. The problem is that I don't know how to return all matches. This code returns the same match all time in while loop, so loop never ends. I need some kind of idea to resolve it.

Comment: Think about what property all items that you want to find have, than see if you can find how to separate the ones you don't need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-1 Which part of the homework do you have trouble with? 
Is it the binary search? 
Is it the selection of filenames? 
Is it the BackgroundWorker thing that is not working as expected?

I see that you have some problems with the BackgroundWorker, it seems that you are selecting a list of files from UI in the BackgroundWorker thread and then creates a Action that will run in main thread, this is a very odd way to do it.

The correct way would be:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender)
{
    List<string> files = listBoxFiles.Items.OfType<string>().ToList();
    string key = textBoxFileToSearch.Text;
    backgroundWorkerSearch.RunWorkerAsync(new Tupple<List<string>,string>(files, key));
}

void backgroundWorkerSearch_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     var state = e.Argument as Tupple<List<string>,string>;
     List<string> files = state.Item1;
     string key = state.Item2;
     // You can now access the needed data.
     List<string> searchResult = new List<string>();
     // ...
     e.Result = searchResult;
}

void backgroundWorkerSearch_RunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     List<string> searchResult = e.Result;
     // Show result in the UI thread.
}
```